# why background process terminated after ssh session closed

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

I am using XManager xshell as ssh client, connected to a remote server, then executed commands:

```
nohup sleep 60 &
ps -ef | grep sleep
exit
```

then login again

```
ps -ef | grep sleep
```

that process is gone!

anything may cause this ? the ssh daemon is openssh 8, server is redhat 7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `systemd-logind`, there is the (default) setting:

```
KillUserProcesses=yes
```

in your [logind.conf](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html). It will terminate all processes started by the user as part of their login session after the user logs out.  You can set it to no, or set the following setting to your user:

```
KillExcludeUsers=yourusername
```

Comment: @jsbilings where is the location of logind.conf?

Comment: @WestFarmer please check the man page I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you want is to run remote command in "detachable" way so that you can connect back to it in the future. `nohup` really is a hack, and as you see systemd will take care of it when user session terminates.

Instead of solving this at systemd level by disabling it's sanitization mechanism, you could solve this much more elegantly by using some terminal multiplexer like `tmux`, `screen`, `abduco` or other.

Terminal multiplexer can create detached session, that will continue to run even when you log out. You can always reconnect to the session later and adjust it's contents.

**EDIT after jsbillings@ comment:**

I admit that my original reply, albeit correct, was seemingly quite terse and so its meaning got lost on you (probably), and also motivated jsbillings@ to write an unhelpful comment and suboptimal answer.

The crux of the problem is, that you are missing quite a lot of "behind the scenes info", and jsbillings@ is unwilling to go into detail how to fix/solve it properly. Big blame lies on systemd developers too.

Finally I admit that error lies with me as well, as I did not give you the full reply, which is rather exhausting and tedious, due to how majority of modern linuces work (because of the mentioned systemd - so yeah, I gave up too soon).

First, as you now see, even the title of your question is ***technically wrong*** as bash does not even enter the picture here.
It's use is completely inconsequential here - any shell would do, as this is system level question and not command interpreter related question.

Second, my reply still stands: ***don't use nohup** (even if it works with jsbillings solution), it is crappy hack from bygone era which ended long before you were even born, probably*.

Now brace for a solution, this will be rather long, but only because it must be.

First, as you can tell I am not very big fan of systemd, but unfortunately, on most run of the mill linuces, that is the init ware you are stuck with these days.

Also, always remember a good advice: "know thy enemy". So funnily, even though I am in systemd's opposition, I know quite lot about it, and I promise you, that my answer is still highly qualified.

The main problem with systemd, at least in this case is, that it is "too smart" for it's own good and it thinks it is certainly smarter than you. Which it probably is. Unless it isn't :).

It is also a pattern, that when systemd's "properness" (which lies in the eyes of beholder, really) becomes widely problematic, it's core team of developers is not ashamed to pile bunch of hacks on top of each other and do something stupid to "quickly" solve it.

You see, systemd is what we call these days as "opinionated". I am opinionated as well, so the two of us don't get along as well. I am even smarter than systemd, so I can actually understand where systemd is coming from.

Now, by making **you** understand where systemd is coming from, I can also give you a real solution. Systemd and it's team doesn't really care about giving you that (education), because it "knows better" (and also, because it just wants control of your system, because you don't even know - education is not the most important point of that project, even if their documentation is rather stellar).

So to make long story short: to not break screen and tmux sessions of millions of people, they, instead of educating, introduced aforementioned crappy hacks like:

```
KillUserProcesses=yes
KillExcludeUsers=yourusername
```

But my goal is different from theirs: I want you to be in control by giving you understanding and knowledge. Thus you are reading this long winded reply.

My words about running your commands in "detachable way" still stand (ultimately), but linux of "now" is not your "linux from twenty years ago". In my experience, most admins and users live 5-20 year behind an actual "linux now" time. This does not help with educational information proliferation.

When dealing with unices, and even linuces, historical perspective is best.

Decade ago Linux grew support for so called cgroups, which are fundamental process tagging and organizing technology. Before that, once process gets spawned, you have quite a hard time observing and auditing its orignating context (cheaply), at least on standard unix-like system.

Cgroup is an linux process management extension.

Quite a lot of stuff can be built from these cgroup primitives (they can be used for resource trimming and allocation, container implementations, etc) but crucial takeaway for you is, that cgroups are beyond touch of non-systems software - ie every single process on a system IS cgroup tagged, but processes themselves (unless in very specific cases like browser sandboxes etc) cannot manipulate cgroups they belong in. This is quite crucial property of the whole cgroup system.

Ie only system software can create cgroups and "move" processes into cgroups (with mentioned exceptions ofc).

On systemdized linux, it is systemd who "cleverly uses" (or rather abuses these cgroup properties) to track context from which "object" given process originated (ie. "machine" (container), service, session or what have you). As cgroups can be nested, militant neurotic autists get extremely excited from infinite bureaucratic potentials of process classification that can be realized: machines, slices, scopes ... bazoongas. And of course you get no say in this, because opinionated.

Simplified: once systemd assigns cgroup (CG from now on) to process, that process is stuck with it.

This way, for the first time (ie since 9 years ago) in decades we can reliably tell "who" actually spawned given process: was it a service, a login session, aliens ...?

You can see CG layout of your system by invoking `systemd-cgls` (or `systemctl status` in any "recent" linux). Now you see for yourself how CGs are nested in systemd system (tsssh tell nobody about it, but these GSs, they are actually real pseudofilesystem objects, ie files and directories, living somewhere).

So systemd first splits process (real) machines population into so called `system.slice` (just a CG name) and `user.slice`. `system.slice` is further subdivided into unlimited number of CGs, each one per running service, so you get CG named `crond.service`, `sshd.service` and so on.

This is actually pretty nifty feature, because now, even if main process of a service ("daemon") suddenly dies, we still know how to identify every crappy process it spawned: each descendant process will have same CG assigned to it, ie `something.service`.

This algorithm allows systemd to terminate everything (each process) that service potentially spawned on service stop event.

But with `user.slice` the situation is much more complicated. Instead of splitting `user.slice` arbitrarily, it is split per each logged in local user (ie. each user account gets exactly one user.slice for itself, that is instantiated once given user first time logs in).

It can be argued this can pretty smart as well, as it allows systemd to limit for example memory consumption of all processes of a given user (per user.slice) - by messing with some systemd knob somewhere - but that is not interesting to us in this case anyway.

Anyway for interactively logged-in users, such granularity is still too coarse in systemd designer's eyes.

So systemd goes with even fancier design scheme: each user.slice of a given user is split into even smaller CGs, so called `session.scope`. One session.scope is created each time the interactive user spawns a login session.

And herein lies the problem: problem is acting on these session CGs undiscriminately.

With regard to session scopes, systemd went with same killing logic for them as for services: once user logs out, he has no business of letting anything run in background (have I said opinionated already?). Screw 10+ years of prior use (long before systemd even existed) of screen and tmux.

Now, we can argue ad infinitum, which is proper solution: whether letting background processes spawned from interactive sessions to run or whether to kill them all. Well, in my eyes at least, proper solution is: it depends.

Killing normal user processes can be nice: if you have multiuser machine and users are "normal" people, it will periodically prune all the crap they have left running behind, on their last logout. But you also want to have tmux with long background job (one-off backup).

Fortunately there is a way, but these are abominations:

```
KillUserProcesses=yes
KillExcludeUsers=yourusername
```

Why?

Both are nuclear options (all or nothing): one allows all users to hog the machine with leftover crap (not good), and second one allows specific user to hog the machine with leftover crap (not good either). Why even bother with configurable cleanup, if you are going to disable it?

More "proper" solution is best of both worlds: have systemd prune the interactively spawned processes by default, but also use tmux as a real systemd service: this allows one to have tasks autocleaned on logout but to still preserves ability to have long running processes in tmux.

You see, data exchanged over sockets can cross "systemdized" CG boundaries. You CAN connect to `httpd.service` process socket from a `session-yourblabla.scope` process.

And that is how you can have proper tmuxified "background", that will not get killed once you log off from the terminals. Tmux communication between the tmux "renderer" (in login session) and tmux "server" (systemd service) flows through unix socket, which can pass through systemd's CG boundaries naturally.

How to achieve this?

Well this used to be a bit problematic in the past, since both screen and tmux were designed prior the systemd crap even existed.

That is also a reason why current autokill behavior happens.

Both screen and tmux have a nifty feature, that allows multiplexer daemon to be autostarted just when you call your first tmux command. This worked quite well for decades (because nobody accounted for processes in login session before) ... until systemd came.

We will concentrate solely on tmux solution from now on, simply because screen is just a spaghetti coded toy and maybe it lacks required tmux features.

In systemdized system, when your teminal's tmux autospawns a tmux server daemon holding your actual tmux session, because of already described CG inheritance, given server daemon is still tagged as belonging into given login session (as it inherits session-xx.scope CG). And as we learned, processes cannot change their CG without systemd, and in addtion to that, systemd intentionally does not provide tools to do that, because it is, you know, opinionated.

Thus, when the time to log out interactively comes, because of the systemd's cleanup algorithm, all the processes belonging to given login session are terminated, even your completely standalone tmux server daemon (because of the CG tag that still links it to a given session).

In this regard jsbillings@ reply is somewhat true: you CANNOT survive automatic session CG tag killer (unless it is disabled at systemd level, of course), but that is true only IF your tmux server IS spawned FROM any login session. Thus standalone tmux servers spawned in their own systemd CG, not related to login sessions, are immune to prunning.

And as we said, we want to leave killer as it is, as it might be useful for culling machine users processes.

Proper solution then, is to "evict" your tmux server daemon from `user.slice` and respective `session.scope` into it's own `tmux@user.service`.

And as we already learned, services are not bound to login sessions and are exempt from systemd login session killing, as they are, after all, system services.

Unfortunately, unless you are running quite a recent tmux (post 3.2a), this is not that easy (it can always be done, trust me, but it will require some thinking - but that is out of scope of this already uberlong reply).

On the other side, I can say, that since tmux version 3.2a this can be made work very, very reliably with systemd and no hacks.

Before that tmux version, the problem lies with another feature of tmux (and screen), that both automatically terminate user server once there is no "tmux session(!)" (ie as in-tmux terminal+bash shell process - and this has nothing to do with systemd login sessions) associated with a given user.

So with older tmux, even if you started the daemon from service, without some hacking around it, it would immediately terminate, making your systemd tmux user service useless.

Finally, what are the magic steps needed to implement this with recent linux and tmux:

1. you need to start tmux server in server mode directly, ie as foreground "daemon", and not use it's autostart feature (that spawns actual daemon as it's descendant).
2. at the same time, you need to disable tmux server's "autoexit on no tmux session" feature, otherwise even in foreground mode, server would immediately exit. Thankfully, in the recent tmux, step 1. takes care of that automatically too.
3. then you need to configure this setup as system level tmux user server service.
4. once system level tmux user server service is started, you can start long running tmux sessions inside that tmux user server service CG, and after you log off the machine, systemd will let those tmux sessions run there indefinitely.

For 1. and 2. see new tmux `-D` flag. For 3. here is a very basic recipe:

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/tmux-myuser.service
[Unit]
Description=Permanent tmux server for myuser user
 
[Service]
Type=exec
User=myuser
Group=myuser
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux -D
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Create this service and then start it.  Invoking `systemd status` you should now see your tmux server running as "daemon" or rather systemd service. Running tmux command from any other login shell under the same user, should spawn it's process tree inside that tmux-myuser.service cgroup (check with systemctl status again).

Once you got this working, if you are feeling fancy, you can now tweak you tmux user service to autogen user services with @ systemd variables and whatnot.

This solution can be, in fact, applied to any terminal multiplexer, as long as it can run supervised in server mode and you'll encapsulate it into standalone systemd service.

**What are advantages of this solution when compared against nohup?**

There are many many advantages against nohup.

First, you probably don't know what magic nohup does, but this magic only works when traditional unix paradigm (every process is left running without origin context tracking a termination) holds true. On Linux this paradigm does not hold true for more than 9 years.
Systemdized tmux service avoids that altogether.

Second, you lose access to nohupped process output streams and it's full process control. Nohup allows you to "redirect" process output to "log file" (in reality it just turns stdout descriptor there) but this is suboptimal (observation, rotation etc). Doing it right requires lot of planning and even then it is really brittle.

Major process control is lost forever: after originating spawning shell disappears, only way to control nohupped process is by PID and signals. No other shell will remembeber process group of nohupped process, it won't be selectable and visible with `jobs` command.

Running such background task from tmux takes care of all that automagically plus gives you several other very potent advantages:

1. you can save tmux "log buffer" to file (ie log only what is needed, on demand)
2. more importantly, tmux backgrounding allows you to still pass input to the backgrounded process when needed (ie passsword entry remain possible)
3. having properly backgrounded tmux service running in advance allows you to spawn unlimited number backrounded tasks later: unexpected backups, large file transfers, ad hoc daemon like commands
4. you can organize multiple unexpected background task contexts by simply having them run in named tmux sessions. Multiple panes in one tmux session allow you to run a swarm of cooperating processes even. More over, tmux pane layout can effectively express their importance or internal dependecies or hirarchy.

As you can see you gain quite lot from multiplexing into systemd service.

Comment: Systemd-logind will gladly kill off tmux and screen just as it will any other process.  There isn’t anything special about them that will save those processes if their part of the users session.

Comment: Not really depends, on how you approach your tmux session creation see my edits.

Comment: I appreciate the long edit, reminds me of those cookbook authors who write a whole novella as the introduction to a recipe. At any rate, I get that you don’t like systemd, but if you are going to suggest a systemd service, I suggest that you switch it to a user daemon service (i.e. in ~/.config/systemd/user/). That way it ends up nested in the right set of cgroups, and any enclosing unit cgroups that have resource limits are appropriately applied. “But wait!” you say. “Won’t those services be only started on login?”  Yes, but if you run (as root) `loginctl enable-linger username` it will work.

Comment: I take this comment as a compliment thank you @jsbillings. Unfortunately, I believe the novella is very much necessary. It is also much helpful than this: here is link to cgroups docs, here systemd docs, here are some mailing lists emails and go figure it out. Systemd is here to stay, so sooner this information permeates admins the better.

Comment: Also into which set of cgroups tmux session belongs, whether system.slice, or user.slice is again in the "eye of sysadmin". System level systemd services can have users and you can argue that tmux is system level service, same way sshd or httpd is. I used to be like you, but really, the answer is not so clear cut. In my experience system.slice parented tmux user service is much more useful than user level service. But for specific usecases it might be other way around. That's why we are admins to make these decisions.